# Send the contents of a file before send-receive over a TTY with socat

Tags: socat

I'm using `socat` like this to connect to a TCP server interactively:

```
socat file:`tty`,raw,echo=0 tcp:127.0.0.1:1337
```

I can also send a file instead of interactive input:

```
socat file:/tmp/myfile'!!'file:`tty`,raw,echo=0 tcp:127.0.0.1:1337
```

How do I combine the two, i.e. first send the contents of `/tmp/myfile`, and then send-receive on the current TTY indefinitely? Is it possible to do it with `socat`? If not, how do I do it?